# Converting media files for HTTP Live Streaming on windows?

Tags: windows, http-live-streaming

I want to be able to run HTTP live streaming from a server, so that I can play back the files on my iPhone via HTTP. I know it's possible to play media files through safari /without/ live streaming, but I'd like to give it a go.

As far as I can tell, the only tools available for converting media files into the formats required for the live stream are for Mac OSX. I don't have a Mac, and I'm wondering if there are any equivalent tools for Windows?

Comment: try this one...may help  http://www.videolan.org/

Answer (score 1):

FFMpeg offers tools for Mac, Windows, and Linux. http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Yeah but what about the variantplaylistcreator tool that is only for MacOS? How to create the variant playlist on windows programatically?